# problems with system shell access from ipython

Tags: macos, shell, ipython

Seeing some weird behavior in iPython that appears to depend on how it's launched.  When launched in terminal, certain shell commands work (pwd), but both 'ls' and '!ls' error out - see below for a § of the OSError Traceback.

When launched with the Qtconsole: "ipython qtconsole --pylab=inline", all appears to be well.

[Additional information: the shell commands work fine when ipython is launched as a notebook.]

[Additional information #2: "iptest core" generates 4 errors - all of which are related to File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py"]

Any suggestions?  Thanks!  Running Python 2.7.5, IPython 2.1.0, Mac OSX Mavericks.

...

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.pyc in system_raw(self, cmd)
   2277             cmd = py3compat.unicode_to_str(cmd)
   2278             # Call the cmd using the OS shell, instead of the default /bin/sh, if set.
-> 2279             ec = subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True, executable=os.environ.get('SHELL', None))
   2280             # exit code is positive for program failure, or negative for
   2281             # terminating signal number.


OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't make sense of *all* of your symptoms, but the error `[Errno 2]` message suggests that your `SHELL` environment variable contains a value that doesn't point to an existing shell executable.

Normally, `SHELL` contains the full path to your default shell's executable, e.g., `/bin/bash`.

Things you can try:

- Check the output of `echo $SHELL` and make sure it contains the full path of your default shell's executable.
- Invoke `ipython` with an explicit `SHELL` value and see if the problem goes away: `SHELL=/bin/bash ipython`.

`pwd` doesn't actually invoke a shell instance, so that's why you don't see an error.
By contrast, `ls` (indirectly) and `!ls` (directly) do.

---

I'm running the same versions, and `iptest core` fails on my machine too, although differently   (`ImportError: No module named nose.plugins.builtin`) - however, at least in my case it seems unrelated to running shells from `ipython`, which works fine.

Comment: Setting the SHELL variable solved the problem and now iptest core passes cleanly.

Comment: @user56870: I'm glad to hear it - any idea why `SHELL` wasn't set (it normally is)? Or was it set and contained an invalid value?